# How to write reducers to manipulate this JSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a JSON like this

```
"decks": [
    {
      "id": 65,
      "name": "deck1",
      "cards": [
        {
          "question": "q1",
          "answer": "a1"
        },
        {
          "question": "q2",
          "answer": "a2"
        },
        {
          "question": "q3",
          "answer": "a3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "deck2",
      "cards": []
    }
```

Now, I want to return the decks object after adding one more card like

```
   {
      "question": "q4",
      "answer": "a4"
    },
```

and that card should add to the corresponding id **suppose -65 for this case,** and the result should return like this

```
"decks": [
    {
      "id": 65,
      "name": "deck1",
      "cards": [
        {
          "question": "q1",
          "answer": "a1"
        },
        {
          "question": "q2",
          "answer": "a2"
        },
        {
          "question": "q3",
          "answer": "a3"
        },
        {
          "question": "q4",
          "answer": "a4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "deck2",
      "cards": []
    }
```

This is my reducers code where I am manipulating the object

```
case ADD_CARD:

      var index = state.decks.findIndex(x => x.id === action.deckId);


      return {
        ...state.decks,
        decks: state.decks[index].cards.concat(action.newCard),
      };
```

Could you please help me here to write the correct reducer code. The above code is not giving the expected result.
Thanks for your time and support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `state.decks` is array, so you cant't overwrite one of array items with object notation you have used. One more minor suggestion: I'd say `Array.prototype.push()` suits more naturally to the purpose than `Array.prototype.concat()`.

Assuming `decks` does not represent your entire state and your attempt was to update state upon dispatching action:

```
{type:'ADD_CARD', deckId: 65, newCard:{question:'q4',answer:'a4'}}
```

Your corresponding reducer section might look something, like:

```
const appReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_CARD: {
            const   {deckId, newCard} = action,
                    {decks} = state,
                    index = decks.findIndex(({id}) => id === deckId)
            decks[index]['cards'].push(newCard)
            return {...state, decks}
        }
        default: return state
    }
}
```

You might find below the live demo as a proof of concept

```js
//dependency

const { createStore } = Redux

//default state, reducer, store

const defaultState = {"decks":[{"id":65,"name":"deck1","cards":[{"question":"q1","answer":"a1"},{"question":"q2","answer":"a2"},{"question":"q3","answer":"a3"}]},{"id":83,"name":"deck2","cards":[]}]},
      appReducer = (state=defaultState, action) => {
          switch(action.type){
              case 'ADD_CARD': {
                  const   {deckId, newCard} = action,
                          {decks} = state,
                          index = decks.findIndex(({id}) => id === deckId)
                  decks[index]['cards'].push(newCard)
                  return {...state, decks}
              }
              default: return state
          }
      },
      store = createStore(appReducer)
      
//dispatchind 'ADD_CARD' action

store.dispatch({type:'ADD_CARD', deckId: 65, newCard:{question:'q4',answer:'a4'}})

//logging the updated store

console.log(store.getState())
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100%}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
case ADD_CARD:
      const newState = {...state};
      var index = state.decks.findIndex(x => x.id === action.deckId);
      let deck = {...state.decks[index]};
      deck = {...deck, { cards: [...deck.cards, action.newCard] };
      newState[index] = deck;
      return newState;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array map function:

```js
let decks = [
    {
      "id": 65,
      "name": "deck1",
      "cards": [
        {
          "question": "q1",
          "answer": "a1"
        },
        {
          "question": "q2",
          "answer": "a2"
        },
        {
          "question": "q3",
          "answer": "a3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "deck2",
      "cards": []
    }]

 const newCard = {
      "question": "q4",
      "answer": "a4"
    }
    
    const newArray = decks.map(x => x.id === 65
? {...x, cards: [...x.cards, newCard]}
: x)
    
    console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.map()` method iterates unnecessarily through out the entire array, whereas `Array.prototype.findIndex()` stops looping right upon hitting the match (first item in this particular case).  So, the latter is more optimal from performance standpoint. And this is why it was attempted by OP and implemented successfully in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59524254/11299053).